# Should debugger be launched always in VScode when only running a file (not debugging) using code-runner?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, vscode-code-runner

In a VScode C/C++ programming setup on Windows 10 system, the "C/C++ Extension Pack", "Code Runner", "WSL" extensions are installed, which use Alpine Linux target on WSL on this PC. Alpine Linux WSL instance has the gcc dev environment, build-tools, gdb etc. installed, apart from the necessary VScode extensions needed inside WSL.

In this environment I am able to write C/C++ programs, build them, execute them, interact with them through the built-in terminal. I use the "Code Runner" "Run C/C++ file" shortcut button to build(if necessary) and run individual C/C++ program files (there is no Makefile and these are simple programs all thrown in a single folder, not in a project structure).

Recently however, I noticed that whenever I try to "Run C/C++ file", debugger is also launched and I get a screen like this (notice the 2 yellow/orange arrows indicating what I am trying to draw attention to):
[image]

I do not remember this being the case earlier, but I think this started after I tried to debug a program by setting a breakpoint, which I later cleared. I've also ensured that "Run > Remove All Breakpoints" is done, to make sure that there are absolutely no breakpoints. Therefore wondering if:

- it is normal for debugger to get launched in this manner ?
- if not, what exactly might have caused it ?
- finally, what can I do to make sure that the debugger is not launched, when all I want to do is "Run" ?

In "Code Runner" settings file, I did not find anything that might control this behaviour, but then I am quite new to VScode so not sure if I am missing anything obvious.